# Extrair arquivo .zip

Tags: c#

tenho um arquivo que é zipado pelo o 7-Zip, na hora de descompactar pelo c#, utilizando o seguinte código:

```
 try
            {
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(caminho + "\\" + arquivo, arquivo);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
```

Só que desta forma não descompacta e acontece a seguinte `Exception`:

```
The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.
```

Qual outra forma que eu poderia descompactar este arquivo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836736/unzip-files-programmatically-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O 7zip pode usar algoritmos de compressão diferentes daqueles que são usados pelo zip.

Tente usar a biblioteca [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/), disponivel no [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SevenZipSharp/).

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou utilizando esta biblioteca. Não conhecia.